# Open clicked HyperlinkButton in a new window

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-3.5

Based on the below snippet from a silverlight control how do I make the clicked HyperlinkButton open in a new browser window?

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" />
```

I'm assuming that I can do this in the xaml, but I don't see a likely looking property.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" TargetName="_blank" />
```

?

Comment: Perfect! But how does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense if you come from a HTML background since the <a> tag has a target attribute that makes the link open in a new browser window if it's value is _blank. Like this: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>.